# Transfer text file to Bluetooth printer MVC .NET website

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to find a way to send simple text file to a Bluetooth printer from a MVC .NET website. I'm thinking in a button that when the user clicks it, the controller sends the file to the printer (that was previously Bluetooth attached with the phone/tablet/PC).
Any idea which library or code example to use it?
I'm building de website with MVC .NET 4

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you try any code from your side.. post your code here

Comment: Thats the problem i got no code right now. But im thinking the problem again and its dificult to find a solution server side, maybe i should go for a client side solution (using javascript), any suggestion?